# Calling a macro when selecting a chart sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I'm using the following simple code to run a macro "mymacro" when clicking/selecting a sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Call mymacro
End sub
```

When i execute the macro manually it's working very well but when i click on the sheet it is not.
Basically i'm using the macro to change a chart colors...so when i apply this to a normal sheet where i have a chart as object it's working but when i tried with a sheet where there is only a chart (created by using "Move Chart" on new sheet option) nothing happens

Thank you for the help

Comment: The code needs to go into the sheet module e.g. `Sheet1` which in VBE is the name **not** in parentheses. Also, you need to deactivate the worksheet (e.g. select another sheet), and then activate it again. It's not enough to just click on it (when it is already active).

Comment: Try changing `Private` to `Public`

Comment: i've tried all you are proposing but it's not working. I think it's related to my sheet type. i'm editing my question to be more explicit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name needs to be `Private Sub Chart_Activate()` since it is a Chart and not a Worksheet. As VBasic2008 pointed out, the code needs to be in the code module for the Chart. Press `Alt+F11` to open the VB Project, `CRTL+R` to open the Project Explorer. Double click on the Chart, eg.`Chart1`.

Your code module should look like :

```vb
Private Sub Chart_Activate()
    Call mymacro
End Sub
```

Ensure that `mymacro` is `Public` or is also in this code module.

Comment: I used `Private Sub Chart_Activate()` in the code module for the chart. and `mymacro` is public. i got this error "invalid use of property". but when i wrote the macro code directly inside the [Private Sub Chart_Activate()] it's working fine. Thanks, I can use it like this also if you don't have a solution to fix this problem

Comment: Try adding the module for `mymacro` like `Call Module1.mymacro`. If `mymacro` is in a seperate VB Project, you will need to add a project reference and also include the project name like `MyAddon.Module1.mymacro`.